# How create SonarQube plugins with maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I have the following issue :

I want to create my own sonarqube plugins (very simple 'Hello World'), so I create a Maven project with a pom.xml that packaging with sonar-plugin.

But my pom.xml doesn't work. Eclipse give me the following error in my pom.xml :

"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.9:check-dependencies (execution: default-check-dependencies, phase: initialize)"

There is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wordpress.deors</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools.sonarqube.idemetadata</artifactId>
    <packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

            <plugins>
    error->     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginKey>sonarHelloWorld</pluginKey>
                    <pluginClass>testmichael.App</pluginClass>
                    <pluginName>Sonar Hello World plugin</pluginName>
                    <pluginDescription>Allow to create the first Sonarqube plugin with
                        the example Hello World</pluginDescription>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

PS :  I have following the tutorial : https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sonarqube-plugins-1/

If someone know what is wrong with my pom.xml, please  help me !
Maybe I use a wrong way to create a SonarQube plugins with maven ?